# Get third party add-ons(Android)

Tags: android, android-emulator

I want to test specific Android application on different Android Emulator.
To achieve this I referred following link for Sony device Add-ons

http://developer.sonymobile.com/knowledge-base/sdks/sony-add-on-sdk/install-the-sony-add-on-sdk/

So I got Sony device Add-ons as shown in the image

[image]

But now I want to following device Add-ons:-

- Google Nexus P8110
- LG Nexus 4
- HTC First
- HTC Droid DNA
- HTC desire C
- LG 3D Max P720
- LG Optimus G
- Samsung Galaxy Note 2
- Samsung Galaxy S3

Please provide me if there are some useful links to achieve this.
Thanks in advance.